# How to embed file into template using Scons and Substfile?

Tags: scons

I'm trying to create a `Substfile` rule that will expand a key to the transformed contents of another file. I'm not clear on the setup here to ensure the source file is registered as a dependency.

Logically I want something like:

```
out = env.Substfile( 'file.in', SUBST_DICT = {
     '%SOME_CONTENT%': transform( readfile('depends.txt') ),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a combination of `Action` and `Command` to do what I want. I ended up not using `Substfile`, though it could probably be chained to the command.

This `RawStringIt` action loads a text file and emits a C++ encoded raw string for the content.

```py
def RawStringIt(varName):
    def Impl(target, source, env):
        content = source[0].get_text_contents()
        with open(target[0].get_path(), 'w') as target_file:
            target_file.write( "std::string {} = R\"~~~~({})~~~~\";".format(varName,content))
        return 0

    return Action(Impl, "creating C++ Raw String $TARGET from $SOURCE" )

base_leaf = env.Command( 'include/runner/base.leaf.hpp', '../share/base.leaf', RawStringIt("dataBaseLeaf") )
```